# How can I determine which spring context to use?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

With Spring/MVC I often struggle determining which context I should define beans, either the `root-context.xml` or the `servlet-context.xml`. What's caused the confusion is I haven't seen any documentation on the subject as to what to put where, in the spring sample code I often see the same thing defined in different contexts between samples.

As a rule of thumb I've presently defined anything that's a service or a component in the root context, and reserved the servlet context for web controllers, interceptors and anything that's only really related to web.

But what about security? I've presently defined it as an include of the root context, but is this correct?

Am I right in my understanding that the web context is actually a child context of the application root context?

Why do we need the web context to be separate?

I've read the spring documentation from 3.0 a couple of years ago but can't remember anything specific to this, I've also read Spring in Action, Third Edition. I would love any material surrounding this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *can* and is usually a difference.

Basically you `applicationContext.xml` is your root context and is where your service and data layer beans live.

`*-servlet.xml` or `webmvc-config.xml` are special in that they:

- Have a `DispatcherServlet` associated
- Are alway `WebApplicationContext` bean factory
- Are a child of the root context (which can also be a `WebApplicationContext`)

But the biggest reason people do this is for unit testing, decoupling frontend from backend, and for separate view resolvers and/or multiple dispatcher servlets.

It's good for unit testing because you are loading less beans for testing your service layer. As I stated in my comments below I usually load my real `applicationContext.xml` like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
```

Also because the servlet context requires a dispatcher servlet you need to register it as servlet like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

So while you maybe able to load our MVC controller beans with the root context they aren't really registered unless a dispatcher servlet is controlling that context. Although in theory I think the `DispatcherServlet` can load configs in the classpath notice that the contextConfigLocation value is not in the classpath.

Also some people need multiple dispatcher servlets because of some of the limitations in that you can typically only have one resolver chain (view, locale, theme, etc...).

Comment: Interesting, I thought you needed to create a test context for spring with `@ContextConfiguration`? I suppose I could include what would normally be the `applicationContext.xml` in my test context? I normally only put `<include/>` in my contexts with the specific implementations in the dedicated configurations, this allows only including what components I need in the test context.  So you say that it's historical? Does that mean I no longer need a servlet context anymore? Do I still need the configuration but to leave it empty? Is there a benefit to not having this context?

Comment: Yes I infact use my real `applicationContext.xml` for my unit tests and rely on my `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to put in the right variables based on the environment (ie dev vs staging vs production).

Answer (score 1):

by default it checks for `<servlet-name>.context.xml` when you just specify DispatcherServlet in web.xml. 
If you specify contextConfigLocation then it by default check for `applicationContext.xml` if you specify param value then it check for specific file.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

you have to specify the listener first in order to specify file other than `<servlet-name>.context.xml` then it checks for applicationContext if you do not specify anything if you specify contextConfigLocation then it checks for custom configuration metadata.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I am aware of the web-context location and how to override the configuration file. What I am requesting is information relating to the two different contexts present in a spring/mvc application.

Comment: I am not aware of that, but to be sure you mean two different files or two different applicationContext? as it is a very heavy object you dont want more than one to be present in your application. or I am not sure how to have two application context?

Comment: In your example you have defined a context configuration for `ContextLoaderListener` you also need to define one for `DispatcherServlet`. `ContextLoaderListener` is the root context, while `DispatcherServlet` is the web context.

Comment: okay.got that there has to be DispatcherServlet I just did not include it because there was no need for the code to have it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need the web context to be separate?

You don't. In fact, there are several of the official Spring examples that just jam everything together.

There are a few reasons that you *might* want them to be separate. Perhaps the most valid is maintainability: the smaller a source file is (and config files are source), the easier it is to understand. Another reason is that that a given back-end may be used by multiple front-ends.

Personally, I like the idea of composing application contexts by separating front and back ends, and simply importing the contexts for the back ends that I'm using. That leaves you with one "servlet" context file.